# Csvhelper write with windows service

Tags: c#, .net

I am using csvhelper with windows service which runs non stop. I want to create a  new csv log file and put the header values only once until the file size grown to 1000 kb and then create another new file so the file size grow too big. At the moment csv file is created once when windows service starts but it repeats header values every time it writes into it.

Do we have some config properties in csv helper to flag size file?
Please have a look at the code and suggest if it can be done efficiently in .net 4.0.
Windows Service code

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{

    private Thread executeThread;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            

        try
        {

            Thread.Sleep(30000);

            executeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Execute));
            executeThread.Start();                                             

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Library.LogData("Error : " + DateTime.UtcNow + " " + e.Message);
            OnStop();
        }            
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            Library.LogData("Stopped: " + DateTime.UtcNow);
            executeThread.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }            
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            Library.LogData("Started");
            while (true)
            {
                Library.LogData("Logging Execute" + DateTime.UtcNow);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }                 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Library.LogData("Error : " + DateTime.UtcNow + " " + e.Message);
            OnStop();
        }
        Library.LogData("Out of Execute" + DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

}
```

Logging code called by windows service

```
public static class Library
{
    public static void LogData(string Message)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        GetData getData = new GetData();
        var dataClasslist = new List<DataClass>
        {
            new DataClass {}
        };
        try
        {

            dataClasslist = getData.ReadData();
            using (sw = new StreamWriter("E:\\DataLogs\\LogFile.csv", true))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(sw))
            {
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DataClassMap>();
                csv.WriteHeader<DataClass>();
                csv.Configuration.TrimHeaders = true;
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                csv.WriteRecords(dataClasslist);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var err = new StreamWriter("E:\\DataLogs\\Errors", true);
            err.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + e.Message.ToString());
            err.Flush();
            err.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please check if being part of Windows service is important for problem to happen? It sounds very strange that you'd not see it in simple case (like basic console app)

Comment: If you need a rolling log, i think it is better to switch to some logging library that also supports logging into CSV (such as NLog, for example)

Comment: I want to create a new csv log file and put the header values only once until the file size grows to 1000 kb and then create another new file, what different would it make even if i use console app or wpf instead. The question is for me to create a log file in such a way where headers are only put in once when the file is create.

Comment: Col1header, Col1header,  Col1header

Comment: Colheader1, Colheader2, Colheader3
---------------------------------
value1,     value2 , value3
value1,     value2 , value3

file size hits 1000kb create a new file.
Colheader1, Colheader2, Colheader3
---------------------------------
value1,     value2 , value3
value1,     value2 , value3

Answer (score 0):

Main windows service

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{

    private Thread executeThread;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            executeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Execute));
            executeThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var err = new StreamWriter("E:\\DataLogs\\Errors", true);
            err.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " OnStart: " + e.Message.ToString());
            err.Flush();
            err.Close();
            OnStop();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {                
            executeThread.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var err = new StreamWriter("E:\\DataLogs\\Errors", true);
            err.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "OnStop exception: " + e.Message.ToString());
            err.Flush();
            err.Close();
        }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = null;
            string FileNameAndPath = null;
            FileNameAndPath = "E:\\DataLogs\\LogFile" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".csv";

            using (sw = new StreamWriter(FileNameAndPath, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("TimeStamp " + "," + "col1" + "," + "col2" + "," + "col3"
                    + "," + "col4" + "," + "col5" + "," + "col6" + ","
                    + "col8" + "," + "col9" + "," + "col7" + "," + "col10");
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
            while (true)
            {
                Library.LogData(FileNameAndPath);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var err = new StreamWriter("E:\\DataLogs\\Errors", true);
            err.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Execute: " + e.Message.ToString());
            err.Flush();
            err.Close();
            OnStop();
        }
    }

    public void TestInConsole(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting.....");
        this.OnStart(args);
    }
```

So OnExecute will be called as soon as file hits 100kb and new file will be created with headers written in it only once.

```
public static class Library
{
    public static void LogData(string FileNameAndPath)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        GetData getData = new GetData();
        var dataClasslist = new List<DataClass>
        {
            new DataClass {}
        };
        try
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            dataClasslist = getData.ReadData();
            //Create a file seperately                                
            using (sw = new StreamWriter(FileNameAndPath, true))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(sw))
            {
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DataClassMap>();
                //csv.WriteHeader<DataClass>();
                csv.Configuration.TrimHeaders = true;
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                csv.WriteRecords(dataClasslist);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }

            var FileSize = new FileInfo(FileNameAndPath);

            //for each 1000 kb
            if (FileSize.Length >= 1e+6)
            {
                //go back to the start to create a new file and column headers
                Service1 serive1 = new Service1();
                serive1.Execute();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var err = new StreamWriter("E:\\DataLogs\\Errors", true);
            err.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " LogData: " + e.Message.ToString());
            err.Flush();
            err.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

Im open for suggests, please let me know if you can thing of a better way to to do this.